# IP Warm Up for all Sender Profiles?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-studio

I have a question by beginner: Ip warm up is a best practice for any sender profile?

I have a SAP with a domain in one BU wiith only one Sender Profile. I have to create others sender profile and i want to know if i create  Sender Profiles i have to do the Warm Up for all.

Comment: Please remember to mark the answers provided to your questions as accepted, for the benefit of the community. I see none of the answers you received so far, have been accepted by you. You can find more information on what to do, [in this article](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Thanks, @LukasLunow. I already accepted the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IP Warmup is normally only required once, with your [SAP domain](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_sap.htm&type=5). Only SAP comes with a dedicated IP address, and adding more sender profiles will not require IP warmup - however I assume these sender profiles will be using your SAP domain.

Probably not relevant for you at this point, but when adding new [private domains](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000240073&language=en_US&type=1) will still use your existing IP address.